# Use SQL to update parent records in hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table that has a parent-child hierarchy structure to it.  I'm trying to write a single update statement that would, given a list of equipment ids, update the record for that id, and all its parent records.

```
CREATE TABLE [Equipment]
(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Parentid] [int] NULL,
    [ActiveInExecution] [bit] NULL,
)
```

So the idea is that if I have a list of Ids, lets say 3,5,6, I should be able to update all their active bits to true (yes I realize that in this case id 5 would be redundant)

I started making a cursor for this but I feel like that's going too far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
id | parentid | active
---+----------+--------
1  |   null   |   0
2  |    1     |   0
3  |    2     |   0
4  |   null   |   0
5  |    4     |   0
6  |    5     |   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive Common Table Expression, and then an `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` of your `UPDATE` statement, to see if the `id` was found in the hierarchy:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Equipment]
(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Parentid] [int] NULL,
    [ActiveInExecution] [bit] NULL,
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Equipment (id,
                       Parentid,
                       ActiveInExecution)
VALUES (1,NULL,0),
       (2, 1  ,0),
       (3, 2  ,0),
       (4,NULL,0),
       (5, 4  ,0),
       (6, 5  ,0);
GO

WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT E.id,
           E.Parentid,
           E.ActiveInExecution
    FROM dbo.Equipment E
    WHERE E.id IN (3,5,6)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT E.id,
           E.Parentid,
           E.ActiveInExecution
    FROM dbo.Equipment E
         JOIN rCTE r ON E.Parentid = r.id)
UPDATE E
SET ActiveInExecution = 1
FROM dbo.Equipment E
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM rCTE r
             WHERE r.id = E.id);
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Equipment;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a recursive query to build the hierarchy tree, and then a join to update the relevant rows. Say you want to update id `3` and all its parents:

```
with cte as (
    select * from equipment where id = 3
    union all
    select e.*
    from equipment e
    inner join cte c on c.parentid = e.id
)
update e
set e.activeInExecution = 1
from equipment e
inner join cte c on c.id = e.id
```